# Bootstrap datatables sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a small problem, I'm using datatables to display some values, e.g. name, country (hidden) and place. 
If I select a country I want that the second filter for the places only displayes Cities that are in the selected country.
Is there and datatables options to do so?

**I hope this is the right spot.**

```
    var dtColumnfilters = {
    init: function() {
        $('#c4s-datatable-trainings_wrapper').children('.row').append('<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="c4s-datatable-filter"><span id="filter-country" class="filter"></span><span id="filter-city" class="filter"></span></div></div>');
        $('#c4s-datatable-trainings.admin').dataTable().columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [
                null,
                {sSelector: '#filter-country', type: 'select'},
                {sSelector: '#filter-city', type: 'select'},
                null
            ]
        });
        $('#c4s-datatable-trainings.account').dataTable().columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {sSelector: '#filter-city', type: 'select'},
                null
            ]
        });
        // STYLE FOR FILTERS
        $('.c4s-datatable-filter select').removeClass('input-sm').addClass('bs-select').attr('data-live-search','true').attr('data-style','btn-default btn-xs');
    }
};
```

[image: Country select] [image: Place select]

Comment: "_Is there and datatables options to do so_" ...How should dataTables, or anything else for that matter, know which cities belongs to which countries? You can easily create a filter that strips out rows according to whatever criteria you wish, but you will need to do the logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is not something datatables should be responsible for. (or be able to)

You might consider filtering places based on a data attribute country. `data-country="COUNTRYCODE or ID"` If it takes too lang to load all places, you might also consider loading the places you need with Ajax once a country has been selected.